# Incompatibility between ngerman and tkz-euclide 3.01c

Tags: pgfplots, incompatibility, tkz-euclide, german

The following code does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x^2} node[left] {$f$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, it does compile, if I remove either the `ngerman` or the `tkz-euclide` package. I guess that the update 3.01c of `tkz-euclide` (2020-01-25) causes this problem.

Comment: Don't use the ngerman package. Use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} instead.

Comment: If you load `babel`, as suggested by Ulrike, it is in general a good idea to also load `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. Also `compat=1.5` is *really* old.

Comment: You can see in your log file `Package: ngerman 1998/07/08 v2.5e`. The package is almost 22 years old and ***many*** things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: if the answer is useful don't forget to accept it by clicking colored checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the German package but if Ulrike writes that you shouldn't use it, I think you have to believe ...
You need only to swap ...
Now I don't know why you want to use tkz-euclide with pgfplots. My package is useful only for euclidean geometry. I think it's best to use only pgfplots and Tikz.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x^2} node[left] {$f$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]